# Can't scrape all h2 tags

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am scraping a website using selenium and python, and the website has many h2 tags in it that I want to scrape.

```
<h2>john paplos<h2>
<h2>john smith</h2>
....
```

I want to scrape all these h2 tags and display them on a terminal.

Here is my code:

```
for i in temp:
    temp = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
    print (temp)
```

This code works fine without a `for loop`, but when I add a `for loop`, it give me a name error

```
for i in temp:
NameError: name 'temp' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to locate multiple elements and not just one, selenium offers `find_elements_by_*()` set of methods. In your case [`find_elements_by_tag_name()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_tag_name) would do the job:

```
for h2 in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2'):
    print(h2.text)
```

To break it down a bit further:

- `find_elements_by_tag_name()` returns a *list of [`WebElement`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) instances*
- which means that `h2` variable is of `WebElement` type
- `.text` is a property of a `WebElement` which we print out

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
for i in temp:
NameError: name 'temp' is not defined
```

...implies that the variable **temp** wasn't defined/initialized when you tried to use it within the line:

```
for i in temp:
```

However it seems you were close.To print all the text within the **`<h2>`** tags you can induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following  [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890)

- Using `TAG_NAME` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print([my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h2")))])
  ```
- Using `TAG_NAME` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "h2")))])
  ```